# Inquiry about removing duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates

Alright so I'm required to eliminate spaces and duplicate values in a list (of only numbers). Here's my code:

```
def eliminateDuplicates(lst):
    i=0
    while i<len(lst):
       while lst.count(lst[i])!=1:
            lst.remove(lst[i])
       i=i+1
    print(lst)


def main():
    a=input("Enter numbers: ")
    lst=list(a)
    while ' ' in lst:
        lst.remove(' ')
    eliminateDuplicates(lst)

main()
```

while this method is effective and works, when the input is say

```
Enter numbers: 1 2 3 4 5   3 2 1    1  22
```

The output results in

```
['4', '5', '3', '1', '2']
```

I need my program to recognize 22 and 2 as different items so it doesn't delete the last 2 and the 2 in 22. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Sorry to the two posters that have already given me answers. I am not allowed to use the set function, and order does not matter.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `dict` or `Counter`?

Comment: Deleting from lst as you are modifying it, is a dangerous game. It's more efficient and safer to create a new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
b="".join(a)  # doesn't do anything useful since `a` is already a string
lst=list(b)   # this is converting the string to a list of characters
```

Try this instead:

```
lst = a.split()  # automatically cleans up the whitespace for you
print(list(set(lst)))
```

Turning a list into a set and back again is a handy way to remove duplicates. It's also quite efficient compared to the way you are doing it by scanning the `list` over and over

If you really want to keep the `eliminateDuplicates` function then it can just be

```
def eliminate_duplicates(lst):
    return list(set(lst))

def main():
    a=input("Enter numbers: ")
    lst = a.split()               # split automatically cleans up the whitespace
    print(eliminate_duplicates(lst))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: since you're not allowed to use `set`, `Collections` is another fairly *efficient* method to remove duplicates

```
from collections import Counter
def eliminate_duplicates(lst):
    return list(Counter(lst))
```

This is not quite so efficient, but still much better than two nested loops

```
from itertools import groupby
def eliminate_duplicates(lst):
    [k for k,g in groupby(sorted(lst))]
```

Comment: Thank you both of those work, unfortunately they produce the same result as my tedious while loop program though. Thank you for your help though

Comment: @user2146234, You're still using `lst = list(a)`, you should be using `lst = a.split()`

Comment: Wow you're completely correct! That fixed my problem right away, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Does order matter? If not cast it to a set and then cast it back to a list.

```
lst = [1,2,3,3,6,4,5,6, 3, 22]
lst2 = list(set(lst))
```

Also, you should probably use `lst = a.split(' ')` rather than join

```
def main():
    a=input("Enter numbers: ") # Input the numbers
    clean_a = a.strip(); #Cleans trailing white space.
    lst=list(set(clean_a.split(' '))) #Split into tokens, and remove duplicates
```